# Icecast: Reproduce a video in a specific time

Tags: icecast

Hello I am trying to reproduce a video from a specific time with icecast but I have not found any option oh how to do it.
Any idea ?
Thanks
Gorka

Comment: What do you mean by 'reproduce from a specific time'? Do you mean like rewind/fast forward? Please expand your question and describe your use case.

Comment: I mean , for example , in a streaming vídeo of 2 min length, reproduce a vídeo and instead of starting in 0s start the vídeo in 1min 16 s, for example

Comment: You are still not really making sense. I highly suspect that you want to *play a **static** file* and not a live-stream. DO NOT use Icecast for this. Any standard webserver like Apache HTTPd or Nginx is better at that.

Comment: Hello , what I mean is to stream a video file and start emitting it in a specific time. For example, I stream a video file from vlc to iceCast and this video file must be emittef in a specific time. That is my question. How to configure icecast for that.

Answer (score 1):

### This answer will be to the question: *"How to schedule broadcasts with Icecast as the streaming server"*

The answer is rather simple: **Icecast has no role in scheduling what is broadcast**

The longer answer is:

It's up to you to set up your source client(s) in a way that they do things at the time you want them to. This could be:

- Have a playlist (simplest)
- Tell a source client what to play at predefined times, by way of e.g. a script
- Use a full-blown automation broadcast scheduling/automation solution (most complicated, e.g. [airtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airtime_(software)) or [OpenBroadcaster](https://openbroadcaster.com/))